# Unable to see ZIP FileType in packIn dialog while trying to import webservice in Idempiere

Tags: idempiere

I created a webservice in Idempiere. Exported it as a ZIP. But while trying to import at pack-in window, I am unable to see "ZIP" FileType. It is showing "CSV" only. How to get "ZIP" FileType in that dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packin (2pack)  can imported at pack in window.

Follow below steps.

1. Open window "Pack In"
2. Create new Record
3. Give any name and save record
4. Attach zip file using attach button on toolbar
5. Click on Pack In button. It will launch process which imports 2pack.

Comment: Hi deepakpansheriya....thanks for the reply. But, it is not the answer to my question. ZIP filetype is not being shown in attachment dialog.

Comment: Hi @DDphp, in the attachment dialog you can attach any file, for example PDF, JPG.

Samely, you can attach a ZIP file, which is what Deepak suggested.

Comment: Got it! Thank you, Carlos Ruiz.